# php page navigation by serial number

Tags: php, navigation, reverse

Can anyone help in this php page navigation script switch on counting normal serial number? In this script there is a var called "page_id" - I want this var to store the real page link by order like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...

```
<?
$onpage = 10; // on page

/*
 $pagerecord - display records per page
 $activepage - current page
 $records - total records
 $rad - display links near current page (2 left + 2 right + current page = total 5)
*/

function navigation($pagerecord, $activepage){

$records = 55;
$rad = 4;

if($records<=$pagerecord) return;

$imax = (int)($records/$pagerecord);
if ($records%$pagerecord>0)$imax=$imax+1;

if($activepage == ''){
$for_start=$imax;
$activepage = $imax-1;
}
$next = $activepage - 1; if ($next<0){$next=0;}
$end =0;
$prev = $activepage + 1; if ($prev>=$imax){$prev=$imax-1;}
$start=  $imax;
if($activepage >= 0){
$for_start = $activepage + $rad + 1; 
if($for_start<$rad*2+1)$for_start = $rad*2+1;
if($for_start>=$imax){ $for_start=$imax; }
}
if($activepage < $imax-1){
$str .= ' <a href="?page='.($start-1).'"><<< End</a> <span style="color:#CCCCCC">•</span> <a href="?page='.$prev.'">< Forward</a> | ';
}
$meter = $rad*2+1;  //$rad; ---------------------
for($i=$for_start-1; $i>-1; $i--){
$meter--;
//$line = '|'; if ($meter=='0'){ $line = ''; }
$line = ''; if ($i>0)$line = '|';
if($i<>$activepage){
$str .= " <a href='?page=".$i."&page_id=xxx'>".($i)."</a> ".$line." ";
} else {
$str .= " <strong>[".($i)."]</strong> ".$line." ";
}

if($meter=='0'){ break; }
}
if($activepage > 0){
$str .= " | <a href='?page=".$next."'>Back ></a> <span style='color:#CCCCCC'>•</span> <a href='?page=".($end)."'>Start >>></a> ";
}

return $str;

}

if(is_numeric($_GET["page"])) $page = $_GET["page"];
$navigation = navigation($onpage, $page); // detect navigation

echo $navigation;
?>
```

Instead xxx here (page_id=xxx) I want to link to real page number by normal order when this script show links but reversed.

Really need help with this stuff! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain what this script does right now, what doesn't work and what you need it to do. I don't think too many people are willing to work their way through it and find all that out :)

Comment: Ok, updated with worked script example! You can check it! This is reversed page navigation. But I need the real page number by serial number like 0,1,2,3,4! May be there should be another for() inside the main for() that will count like $j++; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I were helped by one of the programmers with my above script. So here is a worked example of the reversed page navigation on PHP.

```
<?
$onpage = 10; // on page

/*
 $pagerecord - display records per page
 $activepage - current page
 $records - total records
 $rad - display links near current page (2 left + 2 right + current page = total 5)
*/

function navigation($pagerecord, $activepage){

$records = 126;
$rad = 4;

if($records<=$pagerecord) return;

$imax = (int)($records/$pagerecord);
if ($records%$pagerecord>0)$imax=$imax+1;

if($activepage == ''){
$for_start=$imax;
$activepage = $imax-1;
}
$next = $activepage - 1; if ($next<0){$next=0;}
$end =0;
$prev = $activepage + 1; if ($prev>=$imax){$prev=$imax-1;}
$start=  $imax;
if($activepage >= 0){
$for_start = $activepage + $rad + 1;
if($for_start<$rad*2+1)$for_start = $rad*2+1;
if($for_start>=$imax){ $for_start=$imax; }
}

$meter = $rad*2+1;  //$rad; ---------------------
$new_meter = $for_start-1;
if($activepage < $imax-1){
$str .= ' <a href="?page='.($start-1).'&page_id='.$end.'"><<< End</a> <span style="color:#CCCCCC">•</span> <a href="?page='.$prev.'&page_id='.($imax-$prev-1).'">< Forward</a> | ';
}
for($i=$for_start-1; $i>-1; $i--){
$meter--;
//$new_meter++;
//$line = '|'; if ($meter=='0'){ $line = ''; }
$line = ''; if ($i>0)$line = '|';
if($i<>$activepage){
$str .= " <a href='?page=".$i."&page_id=".($imax-$i-1)."'>".($i)."</a> ".$line." ";
} else {
$str .= " <strong>[".($i)."]</strong> ".$line." ";
}

if($meter=='0'){ break; }
}
if($activepage > 0){
$str .= " | <a href='?page=".$next."&page_id=".($imax-$next-1)."'>Back ></a> <span style='color:#CCCCCC'>•</span> <a href='?page=".($end)."&page_id=".($start-1)."'>Start >>></a> ";
}

return $str;

}

if(is_numeric($_GET["page"])) $page = $_GET["page"];
$navigation = navigation($onpage, $page); // detect navigation

echo $navigation;
?>
```

**$page** = keeps the page number from the reversed order

**$page_id** = keeps the real page by serial order. so you can make SELECT queries to database and ORDER BY id DESC use.