# php calculation solution for pagination

Tags: php

I have a variable `$total` which is the total number of results and `$page` which is the page number. The result is limited to 12 per page.

Suppose if `$total` is 24, the script may return 1 and 2 for `$page`=1 and `$page`=2 respectively. It should also return 1 if the input number is less than 1 (negative or zero) or if the number is greater than 2

Again, suppose if `$total` is 25, the script may return 1, 2 and 3 for `$page`=1, `$page`=2 and `$page`=3 respectively. It should also return 1 if the input number is less than 1 (negative or zero) or if the number is greater than 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615213/php-page-navigation-by-serial-number

Comment: http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/ Try these http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Comment: hi @zod, that is a complete page navigation solution.. I just want a calculation script with input and output.. Thanks for your suggestion.. :)

Comment: can u answer a code with input and output mentioned in my question??

Comment: I used to copy paste . So i cant code. If you dont want to be like me read those links and write your own script :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to calculate it:

```
// Assuming you have the $total variable which contains the total
//   number of records

$recordsPerPage = 12;

// Declare a variable which will hold the number of pages required to
//   display all the records, when displaying @recordsPerPage records on each page    
$maxPages = 1;

if($total > 0)
   $maxPages = (($total - 1) / $recordsPerPage) + 1;

// $maxPages now contains the number of pages required. you can do whatever 
//   it is you need to do with it. It wasn't clear from the question..

return $maxPages;
```

Further, if you wanted to generate an array containing the indexes of each available page you could just do this:

```
$pages = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= $maxPages; i++)
{
    array_push($pages, $i);
}

print_r($pages);
```

Comment: Just need to do floor($maxPages) I think.