# PHP Formula For a Series of Numbers (Mathy Problem)

Tags: php, math, formula

My apologies if this is the wrong site for this problem, as it is more math-related than programming.

I am trying to write a series of 7 page links, in a Google-esque fashion. Essentially, it will be 7 numbers, ***s*** to (***s*** + 6), where ***s*** is my starting value. I am having trouble calculating my starting value, given a limited amount of information.

In advance, I know the maximum value in the series, this is variable, but it is always greater than 7. In my formula-writing attempts, I have been calling this value ***g***, so ***g*** > 7.

I also know the page number the user has selected. I have been calling this value ***p***

So, for example, if ***g*** was 8, I would need to generate these series of numbers, where the bolded number is equal to ***p***:

**1** 2 3 4 5 6 7

1 **2** 3 4 5 6 7

1 2 **3** 4 5 6 7

1 2 3 **4** 5 6 7

2 3 4 **5** 6 7 8

2 3 4 5 **6** 7 8

2 3 4 5 6 **7** 8

2 3 4 5 6 7 **8**

As long as I can determine the starting value using the information available, everything else falls into place. Can anyone advise on how I would calculate my starting value using the information available? If it is relevant, I will be writing this formula in PHP.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is "pagination".

Comment: Thank you! That may help with my googling for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just simulation code for testing.

```
<?
$g=16;
for($p=1;$p<17;$p++){
$start = $g-$p > 3 ? ($p-4<1?1:($p-4)) : $g-6;
    echo "$p :: ";
    for($i=$start;$i<$start+7;$i++){
        echo $i . " ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

SO your Start Page is decided by (the thing you actually need):

```
$start = $g-$p > 3 ? ($p-4<1?1:($p-4)) : $g-6;
```

Output (Simulation for g=16, and p from 1 to 16)::

p :: page numbers

```
1 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
4 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
5 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
6 :: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
7 :: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
8 :: 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
9 :: 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
10 :: 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
11 :: 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
12 :: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
13 :: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
14 :: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
15 :: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
16 :: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

And simulation for g=8, p from 1 to 8

```
1 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
4 :: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
5 :: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
6 :: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
7 :: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 :: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

This is refereed to as pagination and can be be done by doing the following:

- Firstly you would need a result set, usually from the database or where ever.
- After applying any filters to the result set you should have another result set
- You will need the count of the filtered results
- You will need a variable that is set to the "per page limit"
- a variable containing the current page
- a varaiable that states how many links should be either side of the active link

Here is some code that i wrote for pagination in one of my project's, it's in the form of a class though im not sure on your level of skill but will provide you help with the Math:

- https://github.com/AdminSpot/ASDDL/blob/master/system/libraries/pagination.php

Although my class may seem complex as it's used for pagination such as

*< << 1 2 3 ... 10 **11** 12 ... 19 20 21 >> >*

using adjectives and what not.

also ckeck out the following links:

- [php calculation solution for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296714/php-calculation-solution-for-pagination)

Comment: Thank you. I will refer to these samples on future projects. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also check [Zend_Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html), is build exactly for what you need.

Comment: My thanks to you, too. I will keep this in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Work backward. You know the end number, so instead of doing `s++`, do `g--` in the loop to output the numbers. In the process, you can check to see if `g == p` and if so, add your styling to it.

Depending on your specific code, you might have to do two loops, one to get the array of numbers, and one to output them in the correct order, but that's pretty trivial. If you really need/want to stick to one loop, then you could find `s` with some simple math: `s = g - 6`, then you can work up from there in a loop that increments s (`s++`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but either I misunderstand you, or I haven't made myself clear. I do know the maximum possible number of pages, but I do not know the end number in the series. This will change depending on what page the user has selected, "p". You are correct in that I could calculate the last value in the series (let's call this "e"), and get my series of numbers from that, but I do not see how I can know this in advance. I would have the same difficulty finding that as I would finding "s", my starting value.