# How can I create a list catalouge page for my website, without shopping cart/detailed product page functions

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

I want to make Newegg's like catalouge functionality for my little website. I want mine to be sligthly different(greatly simplified) though. I haven't done anything so advanced(atleast in my books) before, and wanted to know if it's possible to do. I want to use PHP and JS. The new records will be added manually through using either phpMyAdmin or pehaps I will install and use either SQLyog, HeidiSQL or Navicat for such purposes. **Could someone point me to the right resources to get this kind of job done as fast as possible and properly?**

What I had in mind was:

For example the cell which contains the thumbimage, all the mini information about the product and the big price tag will not have a separate, more detailed page. Everything user will need to know will be inside that product cell.

Right under the thumbnail image there will be numbers`(1 2 3 4 5 6)`, and when you hover over them, under the cursor, a big version of one of the all available images will appear.

Lastly, it should have the page generation(don't know what you call it). For example there's more than 20 product entries on the page, then the server should create a new page`(First 1 >2< Last)` to hold the older records.

Oh and there won't be any shopping cart functionality. You can't really "order" these kinds of products, you just find something you like and call me up about it.

TIA

Comment: Which is the question? Do you want us to code for you or do you need only some advice?

Comment: Highlighted the question. But mostly yes I need advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm sure there are dozens of books on this subject. I'm attempting a short reply, however:*

This sounds like something that could profit from:

- a [MCV-framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller) like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) (or [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) etc), which could handle database-logic (including *pagination*, which is the word you're looking for), and
- a JavaScript library like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to handle Ajax, JavaScript and other UI-related stuff.
- ++?

Comment: How can I structure the right Google search query to find some tutorials? I need to do this ASAP and reading books is not going to help me in a short run.

Comment: @JimmyK From several (all?) of the links I've provided in my answer, there are links to tutorials/documentation etc. There may take some time getting up to speed with these frameworks (besides configuring your webserver to run them), but they can make things much easier once you've got to know them.

Answer (score 0):

For the page numbers, I recently had to do this. The technique is called pagination, and this thread helped me out immensely: [PHP Formula For a Series of Numbers (Mathy Problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538637/php-formula-for-a-series-of-numbers-mathy-problem)

The thumbnail effect you want to include would need to be done in javascript. I'd recommend learning [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), as it is pretty easy to use for this sort of thing.

This is a hard question to answer because you haven't given much indication as to your skill level, or progress towards accomplishing your goal. Assuming we're starting at 0, there is probably more to discuss than this thread can contain. :\

**UPDATE**

To learn PHP's database functions, I would lean on [W3School's PHP/MySQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) for a quick summary, referring to the [php manual's mysql documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) for details and code examples when W3schools isn't enough. This should at least get you the markup you will need to work with.

For the thumbnails, I would reiterate my recommendation for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), specifically attaching a [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event to the image numbers (this is equivalent to the onmouseover and onmouseout events in JS) that uses the [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) animations to show and hide your full size images. Hope that helps.

Comment: My skill level is very basic in web development. I pretty much haven't done any database related stuff with PHP. I've almost no exposure to jQuery, but know what it is. I can only do some simple XHTML, CSS, JS, PHP stuff(mostly static and some very basic dynamic content). As for the project, I have the website ready for it, but not coded anything.

Comment: Updated my answer for some more recommends.